# Could the tcpclient in tornado can keep a long-connection?

Tags: tornado, tcpclient, tcpserver

I do a tcpserver, which should use the tcpclient in server-client to connect a anthor server.

I need the connect ,from server to anthor server keep a long connection.

Now I use like below:

```
tcp_client_two = TCPClient()
stream = yield tcp_client_two.connect(host,port)
```

I know I should use `.close()` to close the stream, if I do not use '.close()',the connect would not stop? someone tell me:  not use `.close()` not mean a long-connection.

So,I want to know how could I do a long-connect to anthor server?

Comment: You don't need to close the connection if you're using plain TCP connection.

Comment: The question is not good enough,and not good at reappearance.